# Groovy @CompileStatic and Grails

Tags: performance, grails, groovy-2

Looking at article on DZone about improved performance with Groovy2 when compiling with @CompileStatic annotation,   I wonder to what extent can I take advantage of it? I'm guessing annotate controllers, domain objects and services? Does Grails take advantage of it by default when app gets compiled?

[Link to article.](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-20-performance-compared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Grails version (2.1) run groovy 1.8.x

In Grails web you can see the roadmap, where Groovy 2.x integration is featured

http://grails.org/Roadmap

Answer (score 2):

As of [December 20th 2012](http://grails.org/news/1285958) the annotation should be useable with Grails 2.2 (which uses Groovy 2.0)