# Using Grails with Groovy's invoke dynamic feature

Tags: grails, groovy, invokedynamic

In Groovy 2.1, full support was added for `invokedynamic` (see [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.1+release+notes?nc#Groovy2.1releasenotes-Fullinvokedynamicsupport) and [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/InvokeDynamic+support)).

In order to use this feature, it looks like JDK7 is required and the "indy" Groovy jar.

I'm using Grails 2.4.3, with JDK7 and Groovy 2.3, so it seems like this should be possible, and it also seems like it would help Grails performance somewhat.

My question is this: Can Grails make use of this, and if so how?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803763/grails-2-groovy-2-jdk7-how-to-reap-the-benefits)'s a similar question from a while back that covers similar ground.

Comment: Groovy did add support for indy, but the default was only for JDK 8. With JDK 7 it is possible to use it and you can enable it, but they turned it off by default, because it caused too many problems. So maybe it would be a good idea to switch to JDK 8 ;)

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything specific that needs to be done to make use of it?  Any config file changes or anything?  Or just switching to JDK 8?

Comment: This seems related: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11657